# How to make columns the same height dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble making my columns the same height. I would simply like to make the columns the same height. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<main>
  <div id="left-column">
    <div id="facets"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-column">
    <div id="stats"></div>
    <div id="hits"></div>
    <div id="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
#left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
#right-column {
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that because the id's of each of the `div`s dynamically generate content, the heights of each columns will be based on what are inside those divs. Is there any way to set the column to the height of whatever is longer than the other column? Or is there a way to set the column height to something fixed? I have tried to add `height: 1000px` for each of the `id`s but that doesn't even seem to apply to the CSS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use flexbox instead of floats? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: plus one for flexbox - equal height columns used to be considered the holy grail of CSS!

Comment: You can use table insted of divs

Comment: could you share any working example of your website

Answer (score 1):

There are two big options: Use Javascript, or don't use Javascript.

If you use Javascript, assuming you use a library which helps certain portions of your code become cross-browser without a lot of work on your part, then it's *almost* guaranteed to work on any browser that supports it.

**Big Fall Back:** If someone has Javascript disabled it doesn't look good.

### Not Javascript

Recently CSS has gotten a new display type, `flex`. Now, it should be said, based on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), IE 11 has messed up support for flexbox, but a majority of browsers support it (85% support it without prefixes, and that includes most mobile browsers too!)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
#left-column {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  border-right: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
}
#right-column {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main class="flex-container">
  <div id="left-column">
    <div id="facets">test</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-column">
    <div id="stats" test></div>
    <div id="hits">test</div>
    <div id="pagination">test</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Via CSS and to include older browsers like IE8 you have display:table/table-cell.

```css
main {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#left-column {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right:  solid ;
}
#right-column {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="left-column">
    <div id="facets">facets</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-column">
    <div id="stats">stats</div>
    <div id="hits">hits</div>
    <div id="pagination">pagination</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

To include very old browser, you may also see http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns a very solid technics since you columns have fixed width

Answer (score 0):

You can get help by using this code.
You need to use flex css.

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item"><!-- content --></li>
    <li class="list__item"><!-- content --></li>
    <!-- other items -->
</ul>
```

and css as like below.

```
.list
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
    .list__item
    {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
```

You need some javascript code for fallback of flex css.

Comment: Please include the gist of the link you posted as links tend to stop working after a while...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the height of each column to a limit. you can use `max-height` and `min-height` rule. But if you want to do it using Javascript. Here is the algorithm assuming that you call this function after your columns have had their content data filled in

```
function setHeight() {
    var leftCol = document.querySelector("#left-column");
    var rightCol = document.querySelector("#right-column");

    var largerHeight = Math.max(leftColHeight.getBoundingClientRect().height, rightColHeight.getBoundingClientRect().height);

    leftCol.style.height = largerHeight + "px";
    rightCol.style.height = largerHeight + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try and check my code I have use display flex to do what you want done .. check this link https://jsfiddle.net/qpfrtqh2/1/

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I added some background-colors just to see result)

```css
main{    overflow: hidden; 
}
#left-column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
   margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
#right-column {
  background-color: green;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 25%;
   margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="left-column">
    <div id="facets">aa</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-column">
    <div id="stats">bb</div>
    <div id="hits">cc</div>
    <div id="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use javascript for that.
Just leverage standard `table` display in CSS.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prp2udtx/8/)